how to provide default values ​to database data type date using laravel
I am having problems inputting new database records in laravel 10. why can't I make the date the default?
Database
username -> varchar
post -> text
post_date -> date

Model
protected $fillable = [
'username',
'post',
'post_date',
];

Controller Laravel
Post::create([
'username' => 'ABC',
'post' => 'DEF'
])

i don't want to enter the post date just the username and post only why error?
Post::create([
'username' => 'ABC',
'post' => 'DEF',
'post_date' => null,
])

or
Post::create([
'username' => 'ABC',
'post' => 'DEF',
'post_date' => '0000-00-00',
])

or
Post::create([
'username' => 'ABC',
'post' => 'DEF',
'post_date' => '',
])

I have tried removing "post_date" in the controller for new record but an error occurs.
SQLSTATE[.....]: Integrity constraint violation: .... Column 'post_date' cannot be null
or
SQLSTATE[.....]: Invalid datetime format: .... Incorrect post_date value: '0000-00-00'
or
SQLSTATE[.....]: Invalid datetime format: .... Incorrect post_date value: ''

This is an error message notification.
I asked colleagues here for help with my problem.

you have to make the post_date column nullable in the database, and have a default value of null in the database

@Amjad, OMG, it's true. I use SQLYOG and check "Not Null" then an error occurs. now it works fine by giving 'post_date' => null. Thank you sir.
